# Google Cloud Repository push fatal: remote error: Forbidden

Tags: git, google-cloud-repository

I have just signed up to try google cloud repository and am trying the getting started list and failed on the

```
git remote add google https://source.developers.google.com/p/*name-xxxxxx*/r/default

git push google master
fatal: remote error: Forbidden
```

I can't tell if they think I don't have permission, I am the owner of the organization project

I created a repository in the Source Tools Console

I then attempt to follow their direction to create a local repository and it fails:

```
gcloud source repos clone source --project=project-xxxxxx
Cloning into 'xxx\\source'...
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.git-helper) Invalid input line format: [path=].
fatal: remote error:


Invalid authentication credentials.

Please generate a new identifier:
  https://source.developers.google.com/auth/start?scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform

ERROR: (gcloud.source.repos.clone) Command '['git', 'clone', 'https://source.developers.google.com/p/project-xxxxxx/r/source', 'xxx\\source', '--config', 'credential.helper=!gcloud.cmd auth git-helper --account=aaa@bbb.com --ignore-unknown $@']' returned non-zero exit status 128
```

Comment: It's necessary to put the ssh public key of your local machine/user in the remote host server. If you cannot access the server directly, there should be some interface in Google Cloud which can add your public key.

Answer (score 3):

It looks there was a conflict on credential manager between gcloud and existing git setup.

I ran the following to unset the credential manager and it allowed me to clone the gcloud repo.

```
>  git config --system --unset credential.helper
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to create a repository on [Google Cloud Platform -> Development -> Repositories](https://console.cloud.google.com/code/develop/repo)

Following [GCloud code lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-cardboard-viewer/index.html#4), I had to create `default` repository there.

Answer (score 1):

Mistakenly I've tried to push to a repo that wasn't 100% set up correctly.

```
git remote -v
```

Will show you remote names along w/ full URL path origin.

Answer (score 0):

The exact format of the Cloud Source Repositories URL is `https://source.developers.google.com/p/${project_id}/r/${repo_name}`. It appears that you are trying to use your project number instead of your project id.

To find your project ID from your project number, you can run:

```
gcloud projects list --filter PROJECT_NUMBER=${project_number}
```

Also make sure that you are authenticating with the correct account. You can see the active account gcloud is using by running:

```
gcloud auth list
```

If you are still having problems cloning your repository, I would try making sure your version of gcloud is up to date (e.g. `gcloud components update`).

Comment: I just didn't put the project id in the post, I didn't think it was a good idea to give that to everyone that reads this.  The project-id is of the form name-6Digits.  That's what I used when I submitted the request.  In the first entry I inadvertently called it project-number and number was the 6 digit value for the id.  I will edit the post and make that more clear.

Comment: I ran gcloud auth list and it returned my email address so that seems correct.  I ran gcloud components update and it reported All components are up to date.

Comment: Try reaching out to Cloud Support with your project ID here: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6282346

Comment: @BillyLynch Bronze users can't access to tecnical support :(

Answer (score 0):

After running @gtiwari333 command, opened CMD with admin permissions and was able to run the `gcloud source repos clone default --project=myprojectsname` command

Answer (score 0):

just run the following command in the terminal but you have to run it as administrator first

```
git config --system --unset credential.helper
```